# Angular2: Delete element from the list animation

Tags: animation, angular, ngfor

I have simple list (Tasks) with cards (Task). When I delete a Task, confirmation dialog is called. If user confirms the deletion, http call is made. If it's successful variable isDeleted is set to true and send to the list item for toggling a class. Here I encounter few problems:

1. If I click on an item and do not delete it (on confirmation I choose 'No'), and then I click on another item and delete it - both of these items get the class (why? the id's are different).

   ```
   <div class="vb-task-card" [ngClass]="{'vb-deleted': task.id === selectedItemId && isDeleted}">
     // here comes the rest of the layout
      <button (click)="onDeleteTask(task)"> DELETE</button>
   </div>
   ```

If user clicks on the button following function is called:

```
    public onDeleteTask(task) {
       this.selectedItemId = task.id;
       this.deleteTask.emit(task);
    }
```

2. How do I add fade out animation to the item I delete?

p.s. if you need more code or full code - let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I've figured this out. `isDeleted` is setted on all elements in *ngFor. You should have a property on your object, like this: `task.deleted = true` and work with that.

What about animations, I followed [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html).

Here is my code:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter,
    trigger,
    state,
    style,
    transition,
    animate} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: "vb-tasks-item",
animations: [
    trigger('taskState', [
        state('inactive', style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0) scale(1)'})),
        state('active',   style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0) scale(1)'})),
        state('void',   style({opacity: 0, display: 'none', transform: 'translateX(0) scale(1)'})),
        transition('* => void', [
            animate('1s 8 ease-out', style({
                opacity: 0,
                transform: 'translateX(0) scale(0.5)'
            }))
        ])
    ])
],
template: `
<div class="vb-task-card" @taskState="task.deleted">
</div>`

export class TasksItemComponent {
   @Input() public task: TaskSummary;

   @Output() public deleteTask = new EventEmitter();

   public onDeleteTask(task) {
      task.deleted = (task.deleted === 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active');
      this.deleteTask.emit(task);
   }

}
```

I'm setting the animation state (task.deleted) if user confirms deletion:

```
public onDeleteModal(isOk) {
    this.isModalOpen = isOk;
    if(isOk) {
        this.tasksSandbox.deleteTask(this.taskToDelete.id)
            .subscribe(res => {
                if (res) {
                    this.taskToDelete.deleted = 'void';
                    this.isModalOpen = !isOk;
                }
            });
    }else{
        this.taskToDelete.deleted = 'inactive';
    }
}
```

Comment: ```@taskState``` needs to be ```[@taskState]```